# Jenkins delete job if it fails

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-plugins, hudson, jenkins-groovy

As part of post build action in jenkins, I want to delete a job if it has failed with a particular exit code.
Logic here is:

- My current job(perl script) queries MySQL Db to see if it needs to
  trigger any downstream job.
- If not, I exit out with a particular
  code.
- Now, as part of post build step, I want to check if the
  current job exited with a particular code and then delete and reset
  next build number.

Reason being not having failed jobs every 5 mins (build schedule is set to every 5 mins)
I have been looking for a way to do this. 
So, far I have got below 2 ways working via Manage Jenkins -> Script Console. But the same code fails when I add it to current jenkins job.

Working under Manage Jenkins -> Script Console

```
import jenkins.model.Jenkins
import hudson.model.*
def jobName = "renum_jenkins_test"
def job = Jenkins.instance.getItem(jobName)
job.getBuilds().each { it.delete() }
job.nextBuildNumber = 26
job.save()
```

As well as:

```
import jenkins.model.Jenkins
def jobName = 'renum_jenkins_test'
Jenkins.instance.getItemByFullName(jobName).builds.findAll { it.result 
== Result.FAILURE}.each { it.delete() }
```

Error message when it runs as  Post Build Step in Jenkins Job Configure:

```
java.nio.file.FileSystemException: /auto/system-dir/idevtest/jenkins/conf/jobs/renum_jenkins_test/builds/.30/.nfs000000000d587f2900000049: Device or resource busy
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:91)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:102)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:107)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.implDelete(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:243)
    at sun.nio.fs.AbstractFileSystemProvider.delete(AbstractFileSystemProvider.java:103)
    at java.nio.file.Files.delete(Files.java:1077)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1449.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at hudson.Util.deleteFile(Util.java:247)
    at hudson.Util.deleteRecursive(Util.java:310)
```

and the error in Failed log says:

```
No such file: /auto/system-dir/idevtest/jenkins/conf/jobs/renum_jenkins_test/builds/30/log
```

Any pointers how can I get away with this error and also determine the status/result of current job?

Answer (score 1):

Easy way is to change build status in post build step:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    environment {
        skip = "false"
    }
    stages {
        stage('MySQL') {
            steps {
                script{
                    echo currentBuild.currentResult
                    skip = "true"
                    echo "skip: " + skip
                }
            }
        }
        stage('Set Build Status') {
            when {
                equals expected: "true", actual: skip
            }
            steps {
                script{
                    echo currentBuild.currentResult
                    currentBuild.result = 'ABORTED'
                    currentBuild.displayName = "#${env.BUILD_NUMBER} skipped"
                    currentBuild.description = "any description"
                }
            }
        }
    }
    post {
        aborted {
            deleteDir()
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to delete, you have to create another job with **buildNumber** parameter, that will be triggered by **MySQL** job on fail in post build step and delete last build. This will not cause the `Device or resource busy` error.

Comment: Can you please elaborate a bit? To change build status do I need to add a post build action?

Comment: Also, not sure but was reading on it and am able to trigger another job as part of post build: Trigger parameterized build on other projects and passing predefined params such as job_name and build_number. I wanted to see if using that approach, I can delete workspace and update nextbuildnumber?

Comment: @iDev to delete workspace you can use `deleteDir()` method

Comment: @Sers to avoid me opening a new question can I ask if this will work for builds that fail before the pipeline runs? Using a declarative pipeline I sometimes get SCM checkout fails. This fails the build but I'd like those to either not show as failed or to be removed. Can that be done with this technique?